# my smtp got block port 25 by vps provider?

Tags: smtp, powermta

I Rencently setup a smtp server using `Powermta`. But sometime can send email through ,sometime can't. I heard some VPS will block port 25, so I use the netstar command line to check .

this is the output :

```
[root@luck1 ~]# netstat -tuplen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8533       1640/exim           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         7781       1065/named          
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:8443         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8734       1718/httpd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2525                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8536       1640/exim           
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:2526         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          143636     30670/pmtad         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8373       1604/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8369       1604/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27         8315       1563/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8535       1640/exim           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8368       1604/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3310              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      498        7993       1148/clamd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          402068     25706/spamd.pid     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8372       1604/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:80           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8790       1733/nginx          
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:8080         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8731       1718/httpd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8740       1718/httpd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8534       1640/exim           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8083                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8836       1747/nginx          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8084              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8791       1733/nginx          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          7942       1136/vsftpd         
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:53           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         7778       1065/named          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         7776       1065/named          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          7913       1122/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::1:953                     :::*                        LISTEN      25         7782       1065/named          
tcp        0      0 :::3187                     :::*                        LISTEN      0          143771     30739/pmtahttpd     
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          7915       1122/sshd           
udp        0      0 192.99.142.254:53           0.0.0.0:*                               25         7777       1065/named          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               25         7775       1065/named          
udp        0      0 :::55123                    :::*                                    0          143686     30670/pmtad         
[root@luck1 ~]# netstat -tuplen | grep 25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8533       1640/exim           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         7781       1065/named          
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:8443         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8734       1718/httpd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2525                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8536       1640/exim           
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:2526         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          143636     30670/pmtad         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          402068     25706/spamd.pid     
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:80           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8790       1733/nginx          
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:8080         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8731       1718/httpd          
tcp        0      0 192.99.142.254:53           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         7778       1065/named          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         7776       1065/named          
tcp        0      0 ::1:953                     :::*                        LISTEN      25         7782       1065/named          
udp        0      0 192.99.142.254:53           0.0.0.0:*                               25         7777       1065/named          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               25         7775       1065/named
```

Answer (score 0):

yes provider can block port 25 of your server , you just ask them to open it 
if they didn't , you may check your configuration 
in your netstat output i can see that powerpmta {pmtad} is running on port 2526
exim is holding the port 25 , try stoping exim and configure pmta to listen on port 25 
and restart it , and try to send mail again

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively old question however still valid. I would suggest to switch the hosting, as once your port got blocked, it will always have issues afterward.